# Spider/crawl a website and get each URL and page title in a CSV file

Tags: csv, drupal, web-crawler

I am moving from an old ASP shopping cart site to a Drupal/Ubercart site. Part of this move is to ensure that old links will redirect to the new ones. To do that all I need is some way to get a list of all the links from the old site.

Preferably the results would have the page title and ideally I could give it some way to return other data from the page (ex. a CSS selector).

I would prefer if it were in OS X, but I can use Windows apps too.

I have tried [Integrity](http://peacockmedia.co.uk/integrity/), but it's output is nearly impossible to decipher, plus it doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: R, can handle this. But I'm not sure how to do it for an entire website. Here's an example of parsing one page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746256/extract-links-from-webpage-using-r

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing Perl scripts ...

> [This
>   module](http://search.cpan.org/~kventin/WWW-Robot-0.026/lib/WWW/Robot.pm)
>   implements a configurable web traversal engine, for a robot or other
>   web agent. Given an initial web page (URL), the Robot will get the
>   contents of that page, and extract all links on the page, adding them
>   to a list of URLs to visit.

Comment: I am horrible with Perl, and I cannot figure out how to install a module from CPAN =p